# Fresh Install of Ubuntu, After Windows 10

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, wubi, laptop

I have a Windows 8.1 HP Pavilion model 2000. My younger brother decided to put Windows 10 on it, he didn't partition or back up the Windows 8.1 OS... I've tried reverting back to Win8.1 but can't. So I've been trying to do a clean install of Ubuntu instead. 
I followed the UEFI tutorial, turned off fast boot, and turned of secure boot.

When I try to boot Ubuntu from a USB it tells me there's no Operating system on the drive. It clearly is because I can see the files after I burned them onto the USB, stuff like Wubi.  I tried using Wubi from my desktop instead of the USB and it says its not compatible with EFI. How can I do a complete clean install of Ubuntu? I've had it before on another computer, but cant seem to figure it out on this one. I don’t want Windows 8 or Windows 10! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and then try burning it to USB. Some of the USB burners don't support USB Drivers while booting that might've caused the problem.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Back up plan if this doesn't help? Ive used both Rufus and Cyberlink.

Comment: Try Unetbootin, if it doesn't help I'll lookout for more alternatives

Comment: Couldn't get Ubuntu to load with the USB, decided to burn a DVD, fast and easy, I love this operating system, its so quick compared to Windows. If anyone else had the same problem as me, burn the ISO to at least a 4.7GB DVD, I used Ubuntu 14.04.